# How do I make Sharepoint 2010 overwrite all files when deploying?

Tags: deployment, page-layout

I have a problem where I delete an older version of a page layout but it keeps coming back and the changes I made to that page layout do not take effect. I would like to know if there is a way to make SharePoint 2010 always overwrite all files when doing a deployment to a server.

Comment: Sorry don't know how to commit here. What does not update visual of page or it's functionality?

Comment: Both visual and functional. When i check the code using Designer, it remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Typically that kind of problem is caused by a customized page layout. With customized I mean that the page layout was modified after deployment (e.g. with SharePoint designer) and is stored in the content database. If so, you have to uncustomize the page before it can be updated via a WSP solution. You can use the re-ghost tool for that: http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/09/re-ghosting-pages.html

Files can also be customized by SharePoint (without a user modifying it) if the mark-up code (ASPX page) has errors.

Comment: Is there a more manual and easier way to accomplish this. That tutorial seems like a very long process to create the command. Are there any features in Visual Studio 2010 or Sharepoint Designer that will allow me to overwrite the files in sharepoint.

Comment: SharePoint Designer can show and revert customized pages in theory. I have not seen this working correctly. Go to Page Layouts in SharePoint designer, right click the file and click Revert to Site Definition (or similar). The mentioned re-ghost tool works for sure.